# Using RegEx to Insert Character before Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I know I can use RegEx to replace all occurrences of 'a', 'b', or 'c' with a blackslash character in a string like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[abc]", "\\");
```

But how can I replace each occurrence with a backslash followed by the character that matched?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can transform each [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) using a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate and [this overload of Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx)...

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[abc]", m => string.Format(@"\{0}", m.Value))
```

Answer (score 8):

No need to use any `MatchEvaluator`, `Regex.Replace` offers dedicated means to access the whole match value in the replacement pattern: `$&`. See [*Substituting the Entire Match*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#EntireMatch):

> The `$&` substitution includes the entire match in the replacement string. Often, it is used to add a substring to the beginning or end of the matched string. For example, the (`$&`) replacement pattern adds parentheses to the beginning and end of each match. If there is no match, the `$&` substitution has no effect.

Use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[abc]", @"\$&");
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/XspHAS):

```
var s = "abcd";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"[abc]", @"\$&");
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => \a\b\cd
```